# Flag event as valid where the last valid event was at least 28 days ago

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following event table.

Columns are record_id, person_id, event_date

```
(100, 1, '2023-06-01'),
(101, 1, '2023-06-15'),
(102, 1, '2023-06-30'),
(103, 1, '2023-07-30'),
(104, 1, '2023-08-30'),
(105, 1, '2023-09-30'),
(106, 2, '2023-07-01'),
(107, 2, '2023-07-30'),
(108, 2, '2023-08-01'),
(109, 2, '2023-09-30'),
(110, 2, '2023-10-30'),
(111, 2, '2023-11-03')
```

I would like to create two new columns:

- valid_event_flg. Set to 1 for first person_id event OR the last VALID event (for a given person_id) was at least 28 days ago
- event_nbr. Increments from 1 for for each valid event. Otherwise set to 0.

This is my desired output (with 2 new columns added). Note record_id=102 is only 14 since the last event but is 29 days since the last VALID event. Hence valid_event_flg is set to 1.

```
(100, 1, '2023-06-01', 1, 1),
(101, 1, '2023-06-15', 0, 0),
(102, 1, '2023-06-30', 1, 2),
(103, 1, '2023-07-30', 1, 3),
(104, 1, '2023-08-30', 1, 4),
(105, 1, '2023-09-30', 1, 5),
(106, 2, '2023-07-01', 1, 1),
(107, 2, '2023-07-30', 1, 2),
(108, 2, '2023-08-01', 0, 0),
(109, 2, '2023-09-30', 1, 3),
(110, 2, '2023-10-30', 1, 4),
(111, 2, '2023-11-03', 0, 0)
```

This is my attempt. This is incorrectly finding ANY event that is > 28 days prior. Need to compare to last valid event.

```
 with 

event as(
    select record_id, person_id, event_date::date as event_date from 
    (values
        (100, 1, '2023-06-01'),
        (101, 1, '2023-06-15'),
        (102, 1, '2023-06-30'),
        (103, 1, '2023-07-30'),
        (104, 1, '2023-08-30'),
        (105, 1, '2023-09-30'),
        (106, 2, '2023-07-01'),
        (107, 2, '2023-07-30'),
        (108, 2, '2023-08-01'),
        (109, 2, '2023-09-30'),
        (110, 2, '2023-10-30'),
        (111, 2, '2023-11-03')
     ) as event(record_id, person_id, event_date)
),

event_days as (
    select 
        ce.record_id, 
        max(iff(pe.event_date is null, 0, 1)) as elapsed_days
        
    from event as ce
    left outer join event as pe
        on ce.person_id = pe.person_id
        and ce.event_date > pe.event_date
        and ce.event_date -28 > pe.event_date
    group by
        ce.record_id
),

event_flg as (
    select
        e.*,
        iff(row_number() over (partition by e.person_id order by e.event_date) = 1, 1,
            ed.elapsed_days) 
            as valid_event_flg
        from event as e
        inner join
        event_days as ed
            on e.record_id = ed.record_id
),        

final as (
    select
        *,
        iff(valid_event_flg = 0, 0,
        sum(valid_event_flg) over 
           (partition by person_id order by event_date))  as event_nbr        

        from event_flg
)        
        
select * from final
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: This can be done with [recursive query](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte) like in [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z8QGfP7A).

Comment: Thanks @PonderStibbons. I haven't used recursive queries before but your solution does just what I want.